# MySQL REGEX express a line break

Tags: mysql, regex

I have data like this in a field:

```
This is where a sentence ends.
This is a new sentence.
```

Say I want to get the first sentence.

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `file` REGEXP
'This is where a sentence ends.\n'
```

This returns no rows. I've also tried `\\n, \r, \\r`

How do you express a line break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it with `\n` like you listed. Make sure there aren't any spare spaces after the period as that could screw up the matching. Also, note that the `.` in your regex is being interpreted as `any character` - so you need to escape it like `\.` to get a literal period.